# How to create interfaces for ADT's

Tags: interface, stack

How do I create an interface for the following?

```
void push ( int value ) //adds value to list appropriately for a stack 
int pop ( )             //remove and return value from list 
boolean isEmpty()       //returns true if the stack is empty 
int size()              //returns number of items in stack 
:
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing - looking for some idea's... Never coded before

Comment: What language are you using/planning on using?

Comment: I will be using Java